# change owner of a file and it's parent directories

Tags: permissions, directory, chown

I have a file that has 10 parent directories. When I change the file's owner with `chown` command new owner still can't write to file because the file's parent directories still have a different owner. Is there a way to also change parent directories' owner?

If not, what's the best way to temporarily grant a user permission to change a file inside nested directories?

Comment: What you said is incorrect, the user does not need ownership of the containing directory to be able to edit the file. Directory ownership is only required if the user needs to create or delete files. Are you sure the user has the ability to even read the directory? It needs the execute bit to do anything with files inside the directory.

Comment: @Patrick No, User doesn't have permission to read the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user only needs the execute bit present on a directory containing a file to be able to access the file. If the execute bit is set on the directory and the user has write permissions to the file he can edit that file. Without write perms on the directory he wont be able to create or delete files (even if he owns the file), but he will be able to edit them. Note though that without read permissions (only execute is set) the user wont be able to get a directory listing, he'll have to know the exact file name of the file to be able to access it.

So if our file is at `dirname/filename.txt` and user owns the file:

**rwx--x--x dirname**
User can edit `dirname/filename.txt`
User cannot create `dirname/filename2.txt`
User cannot delete `dirname/filename.txt`
User cannot `ls dirname`

**rwxr-xr-x dirname**
User can edit `dirname/filename.txt`
User cannot create `dirname/filename2.txt`
User cannot delete `dirname/filename.txt`
User can `ls dirname`

**rwxrwxrwx dirname**
User can do anything

**NOTE**
These rules do not apply if the directory  has the sticky bit applied. The stick bit changes the behavior completely (the `/tmp` directory has the sticky bit applied).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question I could recommend the usage of ACLs [Access Control Lists](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-security/cha.security.acls.html)